# Is there an SDK for interacting with VMWare SRM 6.5?

Tags: vmware

Is there an SDK (preferably python, Java) for VMWare SRM 6.5 automation?
Or can any one help with examples for interacting with SRM over SOAP?

Regards
Sharad

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the SRM SDK page (which includes docs and a download): https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/6.5.0/site-recovery-manager

Doesn't look like there's a Python SDK, but there does appear to be a Java SDK.